# Can't solve this it's confusing word problem

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

The space of a rectangle is 60 , If you add 3 to the length of the rectangle and 1 to the width then the new space of the rectangle is 90. 
What is the length and width of the original rectangle ?

I tried doing this 
X is the length 
Y is the width

$$XY=60$$

$$(X+3)(Y+1)=90$$

But it didn't work for me , I'm not sure what did i do wrong 
Please solve it ...

Thanks

Comment: Try writing $Y = 60/X$ and substituting this into the second equation. Then maybe edit the question to show what you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$XY=60$ gives $X=\frac{60}Y$

Substitute in 
$(X+3)(Y+1) = XY + 3Y + X+3=90$

to get

$ 60 + 3Y + \frac{60}Y+3=90$

so

$3Y+\frac{60}Y = 27$ or $Y+\frac{20}Y = 9$ or

$Y^2 -9Y + 20=(Y-5)(Y-4)=0$

Which give two solutions $Y=5$ with $X=12$ or $Y=4$ with $X=15$

Answer (score 1):

$xy=60$
$(x+3)(y+1)=90$

$xy=60$
$xy+x+3y+3=90$

$xy=60$
$60+x+3y+3=90$

$xy=60$
$x+3y=27$

$xy=60$
$x=27-3y$

$(27-3y)y=60$

$27y-3y^2-60=0$

$3y^2-27y+60=0$

$y^2-9y+20=0$

so $y=4$ or $y=5$
and $x=15$ or $x=12$